# How to add styling for a certain tag in v-html using Tailwind

Tags: html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I am using v-html to insert a content inside a div (`<div v-html="item.answer" />`). The content is a string and sometimes includes `<ul>` and `<li>`.

How can I set a certain style for the lists using Tailwind? Something like `[&li]:STYLING=HERE` would be nice but if there is a proper way to do it I would like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.wrapper` class and tailwind `@apply` directive to style the inner list:

```
<template>
 <div class="wrapper" v-html="item.answer"></div>
</template>

<style>

.wrapper li{
  @apply list-disc list-inside text-green-500;
}
</style>
```